# How to test how much files can be uploaded to my website at once?

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I want to know how much media files can be uploaded to my web application using Jmeter in a single time (at once).
Frontend: React
Backend: SQL
Servers: DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler sending the file upload request, example configuration is given below:

   [image]

   either amend it to match your implementation details or if you don't know how - you can just record the file upload event using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Parameterize file names using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [Directory Listing Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. Set the number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to the desired number of concurrent file uploads
4. Add the [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child if the HTTP Request sampler performing the file upload and make the number of simulated users to group by equal to the number of threads in the Thread Group
5. Run your test, analyze results, fix defects, repeat until you're happy with the file upload performance